# How to paste passwords to terminal for use with SSH?

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal

Hi I am trying to complete the overthewire challenges. They require you to extract passwords and login as different users to proceed. Passwords are quite lengthy and I am not able to paste the in in terminal for what I believe is OS X design. I have tried circumventing that using sshpass and putty's plink, but to no success. What way can I do that?

Comment: Did you try `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`V` or `Shift`+`Insert`?

Comment: Neither `secondary click` + `Paste` nor `Ctrl`+ `Shift`+`V` work, although it works if typed out.

Comment: I just started this game, and you _can_ paste passwords in OS X Terminal, it just doesn't *show* stars for every character you type.

Comment: Do you hit Enter after you paste?

Answer (score 1):

On macOS when terminal prompts a password it does not show entered characters but it accepts them when you enter. After you paste it with `Command (⌘) + V` just hit `Enter (⏎)`.

Answer (score 1):

The process below works all the time for me, This requires your mouse. Handy for long strings & passwords.

1. [Copy text/string using mouse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSQzF.png)
2. [In terminal, using the mouse, position to location and right click to paste](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zSci.png)
3. [Terminal will show pasted text.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/535Ch.png)

NOTE: Terminal will not display the pasted string(password), Regardless, hit enter and it should work.